# Spinner drop down view partially hidden by status bar

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have a `Spinner` with many `TextViews` and when the drop down list opens, it opens upwards and the first element of the list is almost completely hidden by the top system bar. What would be the easiest solution without having to create a custom dialog (if possible). I just want the element to be shown on screen.

[image]

The layout has an `EditText` and a `Spinner`. When the keyboard is on screen it re-sizes my activity and if I try to select something from the spinner the first element is not shown.

Comment: Please, attach a screenshot to let us understand better the issue. Also some pices of your activities/layouts code would be nice!

Comment: @iGio90 I've added the photo.

Comment: Please post your XML and any code you have related to the instantiation and use of the Spinner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering my own question. To whom it may concern, the problem was solved using `adjustNothing` for `android:windowSoftInputMode` (my activity allows it). I have found nothing about this in [the docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html) and the default behavior is not the same as `adjustNothing` (at least not on the emulators).